# Write a Automation code for background images

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to write automation code (selenium) in Java for 
verify scenario how many background images are displaying and at what interval, it is getting changed.

URL:- https://www.seniorhousingnet.com/

@Then ("^Background images should display$")

```
public void BaackgroundImagesHP(){
WebElement body = Driver.Gprops.GetWebDriver().findElement(By.id("ImagePlaceHolder"));
System.out.println("body is "+body);
String actual = body.getCssValue("background-image");
System.out.println("Actual is "+actual);

}
```

To find background image, I written a small automation code as you see above,

but if we observe background images are keep changing after a few seconds. I need to write a code for how many background images are displaying and at what interval it is keep changing

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something similar to this

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
HashMap<String, String> imageMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
boolean isPresent = false;
String actual = "";
while (!isPresent) {
    //System.out.println("body is "+body);
    String current = driver.findElement(By.id("ImagePlaceHolder")).getCssValue("background-image");
    if (!actual.equalsIgnoreCase(current)) {
        WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.id("ImagePlaceHolder"));
        actual = current;
        if (imageMap.containsKey(actual))
            isPresent = true;
        else {
            imageMap.put(actual, new Date().toString());
            System.out.println("Image : " + actual + " appeared at : " + new Date().toString());
        }
        current = body.getCssValue("background-image");
    }
}
```

This gives you all details including fade out frequency. If your requirement is to get only Image load time, Then parse the acutal and current strings to compare only URL value

Comment: Thanks Bhargav. But one concern , image keeps changing randomly , consider  first time we got  img-1 and second time we got img-2 but third time we may get img-1 again .In this case our script is getting stopped because "is present" is changing to True and while loop is changing to False.I know its hard .Anyway thanks and i appreciate the way of code you written.

Answer (score 0):

Each image has own unique "aria-label", you can use it.

```
    WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.id("ImagePlaceHolder"));
    String image_name = image.getAttribute("aria-label");
```

To measure changing time you can use `LocalDateTime` and `Duration.between(args[])`

```
LocalDateTime timestamp1 = LocalDateTime.now();
Long duration_in_seconds = Duration.between(timestamp1, timestamp2).toMillis() / 1000;
```

Implemented JavaScript changes the image each 3 seconds. Not sure how will selenium handle it, didn't try it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But as per your code i will get just image name but i need how many images are there.So for that How i can loop if we do not have know number of images and we do not know after how many seconds will the image change.

Comment: After page is loaded with first img, add the img name to an ArrayList. Then add each new img. Adding img to the array must be conditional to prevent doubling img names in the array. After "some time" just count element in that array. If I find some free time I'll try to create a full test.